# I can't get my table responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-table

I have this table:

```
<TABLE class=vysledky >
  <TR class=podtrzeni>
    <TD width="39" height="19">Pořadí <br /> Liga</TD>
    <TD width="39" height="19">Pořadí <br /> Tým</TD>
    <TD width="394" height="19">Jméno</TD>
    <TD width="58" height="19">Z</TD>
    <TD width="58" height="19">G</TD>
    <TD width="59" height="19">A</TD>
    <TD width="59" height="19">PPG</TD>
    <TD width="59" height="19">SHG</TD> 
    <TD width="59" height="19">KB</TD>
    <TD width="59" height="19">TRM</TD>
    <TD width="59" height="19">MT</TD>
    <TD width="59" height="19">VT</TD>
    <TD width="59" height="19">OT</TD>
    <TD width="59" height="19">OK</TD>
    <TD width="59" height="19">TH</TD>
    <TD width="59" height="19" nowrap="nowrap">Prům. G</TD>
    <TD width="59" height="19" nowrap="nowrap">Prům. TM</TD>
  </tr>
```

I try to make it responsible in several ways:

```
table.vysledky {
    overflow: auto; }
/* I have tried also overflow: scroll;
                     overflow-x: scroll; (auto)*/
```

ALso, I have tried the HTML way:

```
<TABLE class=vysledky style="Overflow: auto;" <!--scroll, etc--> >
```

None of the above works on my site.

http://skkelti.cz/statistiky/

Where is my problem?

Comment: The className should be `table.vysledky` not `table .vysledky`!

Comment: @undefined thanks, but this doesnt work as well. I have made edit and posted a link on website where u can try it on your own.

Comment: `table .vysledky` and `table.vysledky` is the same in CSS in this case.

Comment: table do not overflow(:scroll), it expands(or shrinks if not sized) to the contents it holds. you'll need a wrapper that can overflow and scroll or reset display

Comment: @GCyrillus Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap the table in a `div` and apply the `overflow` and `width`to the `div`. Something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="table_container">
  <table class=vysledky border="1">
    <tr class=podtrzeni>
      <TD width="39" height="19">Pořadí <br /> Liga</TD>
      <TD width="39" height="19">Pořadí <br /> Tým</TD>
      <TD width="394" height="19">Jméno</TD>
      <TD width="58" height="19">Z</TD>
      <TD width="58" height="19">G</TD>
      <TD width="59" height="19">A</TD>
      <TD width="59" height="19">PPG</TD>
      <TD width="59" height="19">SHG</TD> 
      <TD width="59" height="19">KB</TD>
      <TD width="59" height="19">TRM</TD>
      <TD width="59" height="19">MT</TD>
      <TD width="59" height="19">VT</TD>
      <TD width="59" height="19">OT</TD>
      <TD width="59" height="19">OK</TD>
      <TD width="59" height="19">TH</TD>
      <TD width="59" height="19" nowrap="nowrap">Prům. G</TD>
      <TD width="59" height="19" nowrap="nowrap">Prům. TM</TD>
    </tr> 
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table_container{
  width: 100%; /* PUT YOUR DESIRED WIDTH HERE */
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/aob3hqoz/

Answer (score -1):

Your selector is wrong. To select the table, the proper answer would be table.vysledky.

But you don't actually the need the table at all! You could just select the element by class name, using `.vysledky { property: stuff; }`

Depending on how many tables you have, you may want to use an id. Selecting a class returns an array (even if it is an array of one) and an id will always return one object.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, but it doesnt work! I have edited the question and you can visit the website so u can see that it doesnt work